# TextField not updating giving me optional ""

Tags: swift, null, numbers

I am trying to get a textfield to update its label when I call a function.
when I call it i get a return of Optional "" and the text field becomes blank.  Below is my code..

```
func P18Switch() {

        if metricImperialSwitch?.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
        {
            measurementSwitch = 0
            CWLabel.text = "kg"; TWLabel.text = "kg"; CWaLabel.text = "cm"; TWaLabel.text = "cm"; CHLabel.text = "cm"; THLabel.text = "cm"


            if CWeight.text == "" {
                print("No go")
        } else {

//                 b = 0.453592
//                 c =  Double
//                 d = Double(CWeight.text!)

                c = d! * b

                CWeight.text = c as? String
                print(CWeight.text)
            }
        }
```

I declared  b, c, and d earlier

Comment: Do you not get a warning on the line "c as? String"?

Comment: No warning on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than casting a `Double` as a `String`, just do this:

```
CWeight.text = String(c)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the Answer on this it now displays something but has...Optional("Optional(90.718400000000003)") and the textfield has the same text too. I want it to only display 90.7 if possible

Comment: `String(round(c*10)/10)`

Comment: Excellent that worked perfectly thank you. I appreciate your time on this. i had to change the code to..... CWeight.text = String(describing: (round(c!*10)/10))